Fuzzy Logic: Łukasiewicz "and" Implication definition
I am stuck on understanding the definition of the Łukasiewicz $t$-norm for implication. I only see the definition on the Internet and in textbooks and papers, but do not understand the motivation for that particular formulation.
Would someone please explain the thinking behind "Łukasiewicz logic Ł where 'and' is interpreted by the $t$-norm $x \times y = \max(0,x + y − 1)$"?

You say in the first paragraph that you are confused about implication, but the second paragraph is about "and".  The second question is more precise, so I'll answer that one.
Let's look at some possible values of $x*y$.  If $x=1$ and $y=1$, then $x*y = \max(0, 1+1-1) = 1$.  Now suppose that one of the values, say $x$, is less than $1$.  Then $x+y-1 < 1+y-1 = y \leq 1$, so we have $x*y = \max(0, x+y-1) < 1$.  That is, we have $x*y = 1$ if and only if $x=1$ and $y=1$.  When phrased that way, hopefully it looks like a sensible definition of "and" in a many-valued context.  By the way, the only reason to define $x*y = \max(0, x+y-1)$ instead of just $x*y = x+y-1$ is because $x+y-1$ could be negative when $x$ and $y$ are small, so if that happens we just push the value of $x*y$ up to $0$.

Chris, thank you for explaining the mechanics of the Łukasiewicz t-norm for implication, but I would like to see more detail regarding the definition itself. How was it derived? Is it related to x -> y = sup{ z  | z * x <= y } where * denotes the t-norm function and sup{} denotes the supremum? I don't see the (sorry) logic in this definition.
